# Singular vs plural noun after the verb "to like"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, idiomatic-language

I always thought that only a plural noun could follow the verb "to like" when talking about something in general, e.g. I like **cars**, until I came across the phrase "I like **a mystery**" which did not seem to suggest a preference for one mystery in particular but rather for mysteries in general.
Doing some research I found more examples where singular nouns were used after "to like" to form what appear to be general statements, here are some of them:

> 1a) I like **a good story**.
> 2a) I like **a challenge**.
> 3a) I like **a person**
> who knows what they want.
> 4a) I like **a long coat**.

Are the following interchangeable with the examples above?

> 1b) I like good **stories**.
> 2b) I like **challenges**.
> 3b) I like **people** who
> know what they want.
> 4b) I like long **coats**.

I am also wondering, which form is more common?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use the plural form, while the singular is appropriate when you are talking about a particular kind of that category of things (a story that's good, a coat that's long). *Mystery* and *challenge* are a bit more difficult to explain - perhaps 'a situation that's mysterious' or 'a task that's challenging'.

"I like a car" would sound odd, but you could say "I like a car with comfortable seats".